# How to pass a JavaScript variable to include Twig Template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig, symfony

probably it's simple to do, but until now I could not get it working.
The question is about how to pass a variable from JavaScript/Jquery to the include of a twig template at runtime.

Here is what I'm trying to do within Ajax success function:

```
    $.ajax({
    //some code

    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var partita = response.partita;

    $("#myDiv").innerHTML({% include ":staff:ViewInfoPartita.html.twig" with {"partita" : partita} only %});
}

});
```

The error thrown is: "Variable "partita" does not exist."

Comment: You are confused between javascript and php. While twig includes are rendered on the server, the response is just one response (page). You can simple use your javascript variabele where you want but be sure that you define the variabele before you use it.

Comment: and Twig is rendered by PHP on the serverside. Javascript start running in the browser on the client side. PHP/Twig is already terminated by that time. Look to the source of your page in the browser. What you see there is rendered by your web-application.

Answer (score 0):

Twig rely on php. Twig and PHP run on the server and Javascript runs on the client, so you can't set a Twig variable to equal a Javascript variable without sending the value to the server. You can, however, set a Javascript variable to equal a Twig variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var foo = '{{ foo }}';
</script>
```

To send a Javascript value to twig you'd need to use AJAX. With jQuery, it would look something like this (most basic example possible):

```
var variableToSend = 'foo';

$.post('{{ path('your_ajax_route') }}', {variableKey: variableToSend});
```

On your server, you would need to receive the variable sent in the post:

```
$variable = $request->get('variableKey');
```

Answer (score 0):

Twig is proccesed before you get the response in your client but **there is a trick** maybe you can apply if your variable partita "will not be modified" in your twig template by a filter or another processing, so you can do this:

```
var partita = response.partita;
var tempHtml = '{% include ":staff:ViewInfoPartita.html.twig" with {"partita" : "myTempPartita"} only %}';
tempHtml.replace("myTempPartita", partita;
$("#myDiv")innerHTML(tempHtml);
```

Comment: it's not a trick it just replaces some plain text by another in javascript. if partita variable contain any html reserved word or symbol this will break hard

Comment: @goto Ok is not a trick, the important here is that depending on the role of the var partita in the template, this approach may be useful.